# Mask with 2 character 3 digits and one character at the end

Tags: jquery, mask

I want to create a mask in jquery to accept only first two character, then 3 digits and at the end one character.
First two character must be either AB, BC or CD only, last character can be anything

```
AB999X
BC999X
CD999X
```

Might be it is easy but my regex is not good.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your regular expression

```
[AB|BC|CD][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]
```

Comment: When I click in textbox it shows: [AB|BC|CD][0-_][0-_][0-_][A-Z], my code $('#id').mask("[AB|BC|CD][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]")